# Find ERC20 Token balance using Ethers.js

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js, testing

**Problem:**
Unable to find the ERC20 token balance of an account using Ether.js

**Code:**

```
  const getNumberOfFaltooTokens = async () => {
    try {

      const provider = await getProviderOrSigner();

      const contract = new Contract(
        FALTOO_TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        abi,
        provider
      );

      const balance = (await contract.balanceOf((await provider.getSigner()).address)).toString();

      setFaltooTokenCount(balance.toString());

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
```

**Error:**

[image]

**Followup question:**

To find balance I see - 2 methods. One in ERC20 contract and another one in Ethers.js library.

When do I use, each of the following statements. And do each of the following do the same things ??

> const balance = await contract.balanceOf(signer.address);

Versus

> const balance = await provider.getBalance(contract.address);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The follow up question: the first one is you asking the token contract about the  balance of an address. The second one is you asking the network how many „ether“ has this contract

Comment: You are using await inside another await and then to string… better to use more variables and then u can console.log each one an see if they are wrong or undefined

Comment: @MajdTL - Did not fully understand your answer to "followup question"

1. We are asking Contract how many custom tokens does an address have - Understood !

2. Asking network how many ether this contract has - DID NOT UNDERSTAND.

Why would a Solidity Contract have Ethers ? Ethers are available in wallet addresses.

Can you plz elaborate.

Comment: The second method is used to get the ether balance of a given address. And in your example you are giving the address of the contract as a parameter. Therefore it will give you how many ether the contract has.

Comment: What type is `provider`? how did you obtain it. It seems that `(await provider.getSigner()).address` isn't returning a valid address.